# Can one use SITL (Software In The Loop) for a custom designed drone?

Tags: simulation, dronekit-python

http://python.dronekit.io/develop/sitl_setup.html
there's a. mentioning that SITL is there for only a few pre-built vehicles. suppose i am designing a completely new model of flying vehicle, can i still simulate that?
Thanks a lot:) My drone design just has another set of mathematical expressions for its roll, pitch and yaw control. So, technically I need changes only in the AP_motors.cpp file (here the commands are converted into motor PWM values) only right? or is it more than that? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually, but at this time there is no detailed documentation to do so. At the moment the best bet is by using RealFlight 8 to design the vehicle (and also to simulate the physics) and then use SITL to control it. You can check how to connect RealFlight to SITL at here http://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/sitl-with-realflight.html. There is also a discussion about building a custom model for RealFlight 8 with SITL at here https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/building-realflight8-models/23106/34.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) My drone design just has another set of mathematical expressions for its roll, pitch and yaw control. So, technically I need changes only in the AP_motors.cpp file (here the commands are converted into motor PWM values) only right? or is it more than that? Please guide me.